# How to call CLAPACK from C?

Tags: c, lapack, blas, lapacke

I am trying to call a CLAPACK function from C. I downloaded CLAPACK-3.2.1 (from http://www.netlib.org/clapack/clapack.tgz) and followed instructions here (http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~%20jburkardt/c_src/clapack/clapack.html). My CLAPACK distribution is this:

```
$ ls
BLAS/  COPYING  F2CLIBS/  INCLUDE/  INSTALL/  Makefile  make.inc.example  my_example.c  README.install  SRC/  TESTING/
```

My file is `my_example.c` is simply:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "blaswrap.h"
#include "f2c.h"
#include "clapack.h"

int main()
{
  char ta = 'N';
  char tb = 'N';
  double a[3][3];
  a[0][0] = 1;
  a[0][1] = 2;
  a[0][2] = 3;
  a[1][0] = 4;
  a[1][1] = 5;
  a[1][2] = 6;
  a[2][0] = 7;
  a[2][1] = 8;
  a[2][2] = 9;
  double b[3][3];
  b[0][0] = 1;
  b[0][1] = 0;
  b[0][2] = 0;
  b[1][0] = 0;
  b[1][1] = 0;
  b[1][2] = 0;
  b[2][0] = 5;
  b[2][1] = 5;
  b[2][2] = 5;
  double c[3][3];
  long int m = 3;
  long int n = 3;
  long int k = 3;
  double alpha = 1.0;
  double beta = 0.0;
  long int lda = 3;
  long int ldb = 3;
  long int ldc = 3;

  f2c_dgemm(&ta, &tb, &m, &n, &k, &alpha, &a[0][0], &lda, &b[0][0], &ldb, &beta, &c[0][0], &ldc);
  printf("Resulting C[0][0]: %f\n", c[0][0]);
  return 0;
}
```

When I compile it I get this:

```
$ gcc -I./INCLUDE -I./F2CLIBS/libf2c/ -I./BLAS/WRAP/ my_example.c BLAS/SRC/dgemm.c BLAS/SRC/xerbla.c BLAS/SRC/lsame.c -o my_example.o
How can I get this to compile and run correctly?
BLAS/SRC/xerbla.c: In function ‘xerbla_’:
BLAS/SRC/xerbla.c:69:2: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’ [enabled by default]
BLAS/SRC/xerbla.c:70:3: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘integer’ [-Wformat]
```

Is this the correct way to call a clapack function? Is the array passing correct?

(PS I am not trying to dynamically link to existing clapack installation).

Comment: Well, if you're not trying to dynamically link to it, how should the linker find the functions?

Comment: @zneak: I want to compile it with my code, so I guess I need to know which *.c files to include?

Comment: @zneak: you make a good point I revised my question to be clearer

Comment: The bug seems to be in the source code for LAPACK; you could report a bug to the authors.  You would normally build (and install) the LAPACK library (or libraries) before trying to use it.  This would place the headers in the right place, etc.  To fix the problem, it appears that you'll need to `#include <stdio.h>` in `BLAS/SRC/xerbla.c`, and look at line 70 and change the `%i` to something appropriate for the type `xxxx` underlying the `typedef xxxx integer;`.  At a plausible guess, `%li` would do (if `xxxx` is `long`); a second guess would be `%lli` if `xxxx` is `long long`.

Comment: If you wish to call lapack functions from c, you may also use LAPACKE http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lapacke.html

Comment: @francis: what is the difference? Is there an advantage to LAPACKE? LAPACKE seems bloated by comparison, with lots of fortran code and CLAPACK seems more compact?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the difference between LAPACKC and LAPACKE since i did not know about LAPACKC, but i expected LAPACKE to do the trick... http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lapacke.html

Except that `dgemm_` is part of BLAS and the interface is not defined in `lapacke.h`...
LAPACKE may bloated compared to LAPACKC, but it's not big enough !

A (ugly ?) way to get rid of the trouble is to declare the fortran function in the c code and link against BLAS. http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lawnspdf/lawn270.pdf

Here is a minimal working example :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include <lapacke.h>

extern void dgemm_(char *transa, char *transb, int *m, int *n, int *k, double
        *alpha, double *a, int *lda, double *b, int *ldb, double *beta, double *c,
        int *ldc );

int main()
{
    double AA[3*3]={  2.0, -1.0,  0.0,
            0,  2.0, -1.0,
            0.0,  0,  2.0};

    double B[3*3]={  2.0, -1.0,  0.0,
            0,  2.0, -1.0,
            0.0,  0,  2.0};

    double C[3*3]={  2.0, -1.0,  0.0,
            0,  2.0, -1.0,
            0.0,  0,  2.0};
    int nn=3;
    int lda=3;
    int ldb=3;
    int ldc=3;
    double alpha=2.0;
    double beta=0.0;

    dgemm_( "N", "N", &nn, &nn, &nn,&alpha, AA, &lda,
            B,&ldb, &beta, C, &ldc );

    printf("C is : %10.4f %10.4f %10.4f\n",C[0], C[1], C[2]);
    printf("       %10.4f %10.4f %10.4f\n",C[3], C[4], C[5]);
    printf("       %10.4f %10.4f %10.4f\n",C[6], C[7], C[8]);
    return 0;
}
```

To build this code : `gcc main.c -o main -lblas`.

A lot of interface to LAPACK functions are defined in `lapacke.h` and the other headers of LAPACKE. For instance, to build a code using `dgetrf_(&n, &n, A, &n,ipvs, &info);`, the code would be built by `gcc main.c -o main -llapack -lblas -I /path/to/lapacke.h`

Hope this helps, though i'am not sure to tell you something valuable !

Bye,

Francis

Answer (score 0):

uncomment

#include <lapacke.h>

gcc main.c -L ./dependency -lm -llapacke -llapack -lblas -lm -lgfortran -I ./dependency

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.